# when downloading from my app is there a way to check if file exists

Tags: java, android

hi again guys im using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), 
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

is there away to write an if statement that checks to see if the file already exists before going to the web for download. as i get parse error before the webpage opens.

i thought perhaps something like this but it was a fail lol

```
 File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 String fileStr = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download";// + "app-release.apk";
 File file = new File(fileStr, "Allcast.apk");    
     if (fileStr == ""){
       Intent iAllcasth20 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  
       Uri.parse(AllcastH20DL));
       startActivity(iAllcasth20);
     }else{
       Intent promptInstall = new    
       Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
       startActivity(promptInstall);
    }
```

thanks

the website is in a private string at top of the page called Allcasth20

Comment: sorry about all the edits lol

Comment: [`File.exists()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

Comment: would i have to make a method for that though?

Comment: File file = new File(filePath); --> if(file.exists()){}....that´s all. By the way, Your if(fileStr == "") will not work. You have to do something like if(fileStr.equals("")) or if(fileStr.isEmpty()).....never compare strings with ==

Comment: thanks guys just testing now brb

Comment: brilliant solved cheers guys.